# Loading Items from StringList to ComboBox and selection according to StringList

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I load items from a StringList to a ComboBox in sorted order. When I select an item in the ComboBox, then I would want to know the corresponding order of where that item appears in the StringList.

For example:
The *first item* of my StringList is **FFFFF**, but that is the *last item* in my ComboBox. So when **FFFFF** is selected in the ComboBox, my program needs to tell me that it is the last item in the StringList.

Here is my program which compiles just fine, but it is not showing the required result, and I am unable to find the error.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var ItemList : TStringList;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ComboBox1.ItemIndex = -1
    then
      begin
        Edit1.Text := 'Select Items';
      end
  else if ComboBox1.ItemIndex <> -1
    then
      begin
        if ComboBox1.ItemIndex = ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf('ItemList.IndexOf(0)')
          then
            begin
              Edit1.Text := 'First Line Selected'
            end
        else if ComboBox1.ItemIndex = ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf('ItemList.IndexOf(1)')
          then
            begin
              Edit1.Text := 'Second Line Selected'
            end
        else if ComboBox1.ItemIndex = ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf('ItemList.IndexOf(2)')
          then
            begin
              Edit1.Text := 'Third Line Selected'
            end
        else if ComboBox1.ItemIndex = ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf('ItemList.IndexOf(3)')
          then
            begin
              Edit1.Text := 'Forth Line Selected'
            end
        else if ComboBox1.ItemIndex = ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf('ItemList.IndexOf(4)')
          then
            begin
              Edit1.Text := 'Fifth Line Selected'
            end
        else if ComboBox1.ItemIndex = ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf('ItemList.IndexOf(5)')
          then
            begin
              Edit1.Text := 'Sixth Line Selected'
            end
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  ItemList.Clear;
  ItemList.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.Sorted := true;
  ItemList := TStringList.Create;
  with ItemList do
    begin
      Add('FFFFF');
      Add('EEEEE');
      Add('DDDDD');
      Add('CCCCC');
      Add('BBBBB');
      Add('AAAAA');
    end;
  ComboBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    begin
      ComboBox1.Items.AddStrings(ItemList);
    end
  finally
    begin
    ComboBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
    end
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Difficult to know what your program is doing, what it is expected to do, and how this fails to meet your needs. Every single call you make to `ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf` will return `-1`, given the content of the combo. Please try and improve the question.

Comment: Yes it is always returning `-1`. If the selected item in the `ComboBox` is equal to the **Fisrt Line** of `TStringList` then do something and for **Second Line** so on..

Comment: I don't want to use `AAAAA`. I want to use the **String of First Line**, **Second Line**. `AAAA` may be varible. It will be changed then the `TSringList` will be updated again and `ComboBox` will be updated accordingly.

Comment: Please don't add the details in comments. Please edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Identifying the problem

> ```
>     if ComboBox1.ItemIndex = ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf('ItemList.IndexOf(0)') then
>     begin
>       Edit1.Text := 'First Line Selected'
>     end
> ```

Here you investigate whether the index of the selected item in the combobox is equal to the index of the text *'ItemList.IndexOf(0)'* within the items of the ComboBox. You let the ComboBox search for the string *'ItemList.IndexOf(0)'* in its items. You only added *'FFFFF'* .. *'AAAAA'*, so the string *'ItemList.IndexOf(0)'* does not appear in the ComboBox. And thus [`ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TStrings.IndexOf) will return `-1`.

The selected item index in the ComboBox is `0` to `5` (because there are six items, starting at `0`), so `ComboBox1.ItemIndex` will not be `-1` and thus this equation results to False. As will the other five similar `if`-statements. That is the reason why your edit box is not updated in the way you expected.

#### The solution:

Compare the selected ComboBox item with all the items in the StringList `ItemList`:

```
    if ComboBox1.Text = ItemList[0] then
    begin
      Edit1.Text := 'First Line Selected'
    end
    else if ComboBox1.Text = ItemList[1] then
    begin
      Edit1.Text := 'Second Line Selected'
    end
    ...
```

This code with seven `if`-statements could be refactored to:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case ItemList.IndexOf(ComboBox1.Text) of
    0: Edit1.Text := 'First line Selected';
    1: Edit1.Text := 'Second line Selected';
    2: Edit1.Text := 'Third line Selected';
    3: Edit1.Text := 'Fourth line Selected';
    4: Edit1.Text := 'Fifth line Selected';
    5: Edit1.Text := 'Sixth line Selected';
  else
    Edit1.Text := 'Select items';
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, you could parametrize this into one single `if`-statement:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  OrderStrings: array[0..5] of String = ('First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth',
    'Fifth', 'Sixth');
begin
  if ComboBox1.ItemIndex = -1 then
    Edit1.Text := 'Select items'
  else
    Edit1.Text := Format('%s line selected',
      [OrderStrings[ItemList.IndexOf(ComboBox1.Text)]]);
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

In this situation, I would store the `TStringList` indexes directly in the `TComboBox` itself, then use them when needed, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  ComboBox1.Sorted := true;
  ItemList := TStringList.Create;
  ItemList.Add('FFFFF');
  ItemList.Add('EEEEE');
  ItemList.Add('DDDDD');
  ItemList.Add('CCCCC');
  ItemList.Add('BBBBB');
  ItemList.Add('AAAAA');
  ComboBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for I := 0 to ItemList.Count-1 do begin
      ComboBox1.Items.AddObject(ItemList[I], TObject(I));
    end;
  finally
    ComboBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  Idx := ComboBox1.ItemIndex;
  if Idx = -1 then begin
    Edit1.Text := 'Select Items';
  end else
  begin
    case Integer(ComboBox1.Items.Objects[Idx]) of
      0: Edit1.Text := 'First Line Selected';
      1: Edit1.Text := 'Second Line Selected';
      2: Edit1.Text := 'Third Line Selected';
      3: Edit1.Text := 'Forth Line Selected';
      4: Edit1.Text := 'Fifth Line Selected';
      5: Edit1.Text := 'Sixth Line Selected';
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: small remark, `TObject(I)` will cause problems on ARC platforms ;)

Comment: This code is VCL, so it won't run on ARC systems. If you need to migrate to ARC, this code has to be migrated to FireMonkey first. But FireMonkey's `TComboBox` does not have a `Sorted` property, so this code has to be re-written anyway to do manual sorting, in which case I would suggest using a lookup array/dictionary to map indexes between the two lists.